# removing page title in drupal page

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal 7 site, where I created a new page which became my front page.

Drupal requires that the page have a title and I've found no way of removing the title from showing on the page. At the moment, I have the title as "Welcome".
I'd like to remove it completely from the page or make it invisible. 
I'm looking for the easiest method to accomplish this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, Did you tried this module https://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title
As far as i know this does not require any coding effort.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way would be by css.  You can do something like this (might need to change this depending on your site html structure):

```
.front h1#page-title {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It worked. I've spent months trying to figure this out. Every suggested answer on other forums was far more complex and never worked. thanks

Comment: Months?!!  Wow, good to hear that I just put that headache to rest :-)).

Comment: I think the style will be applied to every page right? I am not sure about this, actually it's a doubt please clarify

Answer (score 5):

> 1 - you can create file page--front.tpl.php in theme dir and you can
>   hide the title .

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
   <!--   <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
     <?php //print $title; ?>
    </h1></h2>-->
 <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

> 2 - you can use css Rule to hide this title
>
> 3- you can use hook_page_alter or hook_preprocess_page
>      add this code

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) { drupal_set_title('');}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to consider to use [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) to accomplish this. 
The display suite package has a module named Display Suite Extras which provides additional granular features such as disabling all blocks from the site theme, assigning a title manually or having the choice to remove the title.

The following steps would be carried out to accomplish the same:

1. First enable 'View mode per node' from Extras field in **Administer >> Structure >> Display Suite >> Extras** tab and check both `View mode per node` and `Page title options`.
2. Next step would be enable our custom View mode to be available to use in our content type nodes' display. Navigate to **Administer >> Structure >> Content Types >> your_content_type**, Create a specific View mode without the title being displayed (the option would be `Custom page title` where Page Title could be set as Hide) and save the settings. Alternatively one could clone the Full page display mode for the new view mode (if the only change between a normal node and a node in the front page is the title) and make change to the title alone.
3. Navigate to the Edit page (node/our-node-id/edit) of our node which should be used as the Site front page. An additional tab named `Display Settings` would be available likely below the Publishing options where our new View mode can be selected and save the node.

This would ensure that the front page node would not have its title displayed. Though the process might sound a bit too lengthy or even complicated for a novice user to Display Suite this provides a certain advantage of choosing to enable or disable the functionality at will from the admin UI granting flexibility which would be evident on a long run.

Another code free method of doing this would be using [Exclude Node Title](https://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module to do so as mentioned by user [Rama raju dantuluri](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6816/rama-raju-dantuluri) in the comment.

Alternatively you could create a front page template named [`page--front.tpl.php`](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) in your theme sans the `$title` to attain the result.

Comment: Great information. I never knew this Display Suite Module. Hope it will be more flexible for customizing the front
 page!

Comment: Not merely the front page but in general any node page in full page view or as a list in teaser view in addition to some nice integration with other modules such as `Views`

Comment: Integrating with views is really a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive method I have found to remove the node title from the front page or any other content type is by utilizing the Title module https://www.drupal.org/project/title.
This module has been developed to convert node titles to make use of the Field API in order to make nodes fully translatable. Editing of the node titles is made available via the Manage Display tab.